# SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," -- React w Typescript (.tsx)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I know several variations of this question have been asked. But, I haven't been able to find a solution for this particular case. Apologies in advance if I've overlooked something.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Unexpected token, expected "," (25:25)

function render( basename:string ) {
                         ^
```

Here's the function that is being pointed to in **index.tsx**:

```
function render( basename:string ) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <StrictMode>
      <Router basename={basename}>
        ...
      </Router>
    </StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById(target),
  );
};
```

One thing to note, the red error line doesn't show up in the code. It just breaks with the above error when trying to serve my UI container. I'm using webpack to serve using a few plugins in my **webpack.config.js**. I have typescript installed. I'm wondering if this is a linter error?

Here's the local **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["jest", "cypress", "@testing-library/cypress", "@testing-library/jest-dom"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "test", "webpack.config.js", "jest.config.js", "babel.config.js"]
}
```

... which extends

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  }
```

edit:
.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "cypress/globals": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:cypress/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["cypress"]
}
```

Comment: It looks like the TS is not being transpiled into JS, and instead is being directly executed by the browser.

Comment: _"getting the following error"_ when you do _what_? You say you're wondering if it's a linter error, so is it happening when you try to run the linter? What's the linter config?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hm interesting. What is this typically caused by?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just added the eslintrc. Not much in there. But to answer your question, I'm getting this error when serving my UI container locally.

Comment: Then the lint configuration (which appears to mostly be about your E2E tests) is presumably not relevant, but the details of the UI container might be. Give a [mre].

Comment: Try to update your tsconfig with `"include": ["src/**/*"]`